# File System indexing

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating an application were I need to scan a directory hive to find a certain file.

I also want to better understand how indexing works.

Can anyone point me to any resource preferably in C# that shows how I can create a basic index for file system searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it sounds like you need a library for doing searches.

Lucene is a java search library, which has been [ported to C#](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/).